# ¿Hay forma de generar automáticamente la consulta SQL de creación de tabla desde un dataframe de R?

Tags: r

¿alguien sabe si hay forma en R de generar automáticamente la consulta SQL de creación de tabla desde un dataframe similar, por ejemplo, a la opción de SQL Server Management Studio y su asistente de importación de datos en el que a partir de un archivo plano la misma herramienta lo analiza y ya no es necesario hacer el CREATE TABLE...?

Comment: ¿Necesitas realmente el Script de creación de tabla? ¿no te sirve salvar directamente un `data.frame` en una nueva tabla SQL?

Comment: Pues si, en realidad eso me sirve, con slqSave(..., verbose = T) muestra el create, ya solo hay que ir al manejador de base de datos si es que requerimos hacer algún cambio en algún tipo de dato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si usas el paquete `DBI` puedes generar la consulta de creación de tabla así:

```
sqlCreateTable(ANSI(), "mi_tabla", mtcars)

<SQL> CREATE TABLE "mi_tabla" (
  "row_names" TEXT,
  "mpg" DOUBLE,
  "cyl" DOUBLE,
  "disp" DOUBLE,
  "hp" DOUBLE,
  "drat" DOUBLE,
  "wt" DOUBLE,
  "qsec" DOUBLE,
  "vs" DOUBLE,
  "am" DOUBLE,
  "gear" DOUBLE,
  "carb" DOUBLE
)
```

La conexión `ANSI()` permite justamente generar una script de creación de tabla con el estándar `ANSI SQL 99`

Comment: No conocía esa función, gracias Patricio